# Delete SharePoint item ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net

I'm having a problem with the delete function using ASP.NET mvc I can't seem to get how the delete works here. Should I create another method in the custom class for the delete? How does that work?

Here's my custom class that shows the item details

**Custom.cs**

```
public static Formular GetFormular(int itemId, ClientContext ctx, string listName)
        {
            var web = ctx.Web;
            var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            var formular = list.GetItemById(itemId);
            ctx.Load(formular,
                item => item["Title"],
                item => item["TemplateVersion"],
                item => item["TemplateNumber"]
            ctx.Load(formular.AttachmentFiles);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            var model = new Formular
            {
                TemplateName = formular["Title"] as string != null ? formular["Title"] as string : string.Empty,
                TemplateVersion = formular["TemplateVersion"] as string,
                TemplateNumber = formular["TemplateNumber"] as string
            };

            return model;
        }
```

i then call this to my controller
**Controller**

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {

            User spUser = null;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            int currentItem = id.Value;

            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Request.Url.Query);
                    queryString.Remove("id");
                    ViewBag.CopyFormular = "./new/?id=" + currentItem + "&" + queryString;

                    var model = custom.GetFormular(currentItem, clientContext, "listName");
                    return View(model);

                }
            }

            return View();
        }
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            User spUser = null;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            int currentItem = id.Value;
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Request.Url.Query);
                    queryString.Remove("id");
                    ViewBag.CopyFormular = "./new/?id=" + currentItem + "&" + queryString;

                    var model = Customizations.GetFormular(currentItem, clientContext, "listName");
                    model.Delete();

                }
            }

            return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do  here. Are you trying to delete the SharePoint list item using the MVC application? If yes, then read on:

The delete action is your code is only deleting the model. The GetFormular method, only fetches the sharepoint list item, then creates a model using its various properties and returns the model. There is no code to actually delete the list item from sharepoint.

To delete the item you should write a new method: DeleteFormular
Try this code in the DeleteFormular method:

```
public static Formular DeleteFormular(int itemId, ClientContext ctx, string listName)
        {
            var web = ctx.Web;
            var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            var formular = list.GetItemById(itemId);
            formular.DeleteObject();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
           
        }
```